# Replacing default DateTime Value in SQL Server insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to insert data into a table in SQl Server, and I want the DateTime variables to be nullable, but whenever the user enters "", it is entered into the server as "1900-01-01 12:00:00". I tried to modify the insert statement to include a NULLIF, but when I do, I receive an incorrect syntax error, and I'm really stuck as to how to correct it. I've been to Microsoft's website and read the documentation, but I could not find an example of using a NULLIF on insert. The idea here is I want to compare the passed value to "", and if they are the same, return/insert NULL, if not insert the given value. I'm almost certain I have the right idea here, but I'm having trouble with the syntax of it. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Please find the code below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUser_Insert]
    @Company varchar(10), 
    @PartNum varchar(500), 
    @Plant varchar(10), 
    @ForeDate date, 
    @Inactive bit, 
    @ForeQty decimal(18,8), 
    @ForeQtyUOM varchar(10), 
    @ConsumedQty decimal(18,8), 
    @OrigForecastQty_c decimal(18,8), 
    @SumOrderQty decimal(18,8), 
    @NewForecastQty decimal (18,8), 
    @NewInactive bit, 
    @LastUpdatedDate datetime
AS
begin 
    insert into dbo.ExampleDb (Company, PartNum, Plant, ForeDate, Inactive, ForeQty, ForeQtyUOM, ConsumedQty, OrigForecastQty_c, SumOrderQty, NewForecastQty, NewInactive, LastUpdatedDate)
    values (@Company, @PartNum, @Plant, ForeDate = NULLIF(@ForeDate, ""), @Inactive, @ForeQty, @ForeQtyUOM, @ConsumedQty, @OrigForecastQty_c, @SumOrderQty, @NewForecastQty, @NewInactive, @LastUpdatedDate);
end
```

This is the table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExampleDb]
(
    [Company] VARCHAR(10) NULL ,
    [PartNum] VARCHAR(500), 
    [Plant] VARCHAR(10) NULL, 
    [ForeDate] DATE NULL, 
    [Inactive] BIT NULL, 
    [ForeQty] DECIMAL(18, 8) NULL, 
    [ForeQtyUOM] VARCHAR(10) NULL, 
    [ConsumedQty] DECIMAL(18, 8) NULL, 
    [OrigForecastQty_c] DECIMAL(18, 8) NULL, 
    [SumOrderQty] DECIMAL(18, 8) NULL, 
    [NewForecastQty] DECIMAL(18, 8) NULL, 
    [NewInactive] BIT NULL, 
    [LastUpdatedDate] DATETIME NULL, 
    
)
```

Comment: Does **ForeDate** have a default value in your table?

Comment: Why is your "user" (which presumably means the application you wrote) providing a value for `@LastUpdateDate`? Usually this would be set within your stored procedure. But the real issue is how you are executing the stored procedure. If you pass NULL, then NULL will be inserted. If you attempt to pass an empty string, that unfortunately gets implicitly converted to the datetime you have discovered. So pass NULL, not an empty string.

Comment: And I just realized that you specifically state "datetime" in your description - of which there is only one parameter / column of that type. But you also specifically mention ForeDate which is date (not datetime). Please clear up the inconsistency - a DATE datatype will generally not be displayed by most applications with a time component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your values construct just needs the *nullif* statement with the correct empty string and no assignment/alias

```
values (..., NULLIF(@ForeDate, ''), ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
insert into dbo.ExampleDb (Company, PartNum, Plant, ForeDate, Inactive, ForeQty, ForeQtyUOM, ConsumedQty, OrigForecastQty_c, SumOrderQty, NewForecastQty, NewInactive, LastUpdatedDate)
select @Company, @PartNum, @Plant, NULLIF(@ForeDate, ""), @Inactive, @ForeQty, @ForeQtyUOM, @ConsumedQty, @OrigForecastQty_c, @SumOrderQty, @NewForecastQty, @NewInactive, @LastUpdatedDate;
```

This will fix the "Syntax Error" issue, but I'm not sure that it is going to fix your default date problem though, as it may be caused by a trigger or your table definition.

Comment: When I try to implement your solution, I receive the following error "SQL80001: An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name."

Comment: The double quote character is NOT a string delimiter.

Comment: @SMor Depends on the settings, but yep, you are probably right.  Been a while for me, I will correct.

Comment: @MuhammadFerr OK, I will correct and doble-check it this time.  One issue however is whether by `""` you mean that `@ForeDate` is an empty string (probably) or do you mean that is is a string that actually contains quotation marks like `'""'`?  (I am going to assume the former, unless you say otherwise).

Comment: Alright update: changing it from "" to '' DID remove the error, however, a new one has now made an appearance, 2 in fact, on of the equals operator and one on the @ForeDate itself. "SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near =." and "SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near '@ForeDate'. Expecting '(', or SELECT" respectively

Comment: @MuhammadFerr Actually I cannot double-check it without the table definition.

Comment: @MuhammadFerr OK, just take out the `ForeDate = ` part.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I'll update the question with the table definition, SRRY this was a goof up on my part for not including it in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
begin 
if  @ForeDate = ''
begin
set @ForeDate = null
end
    insert into dbo.ExampleDb (Company, PartNum, Plant, ForeDate, Inactive, ForeQty, ForeQtyUOM, ConsumedQty, OrigForecastQty_c, SumOrderQty, NewForecastQty, NewInactive, LastUpdatedDate)
    values (@Company, @PartNum, @Plant, @ForeDate, @Inactive, @ForeQty, @ForeQtyUOM, @ConsumedQty, @OrigForecastQty_c, @SumOrderQty, @NewForecastQty, @NewInactive, @LastUpdatedDate);
end
```

or

```
 insert into dbo.ExampleDb (Company, PartNum, Plant, ForeDate, Inactive, ForeQty, ForeQtyUOM, ConsumedQty, OrigForecastQty_c, SumOrderQty, NewForecastQty, NewInactive, LastUpdatedDate)
  values (@Company, @PartNum, @Plant, ForeDate = NULLIF(@ForeDate, '' no ""), @Inactive, @ForeQty, @ForeQtyUOM, @ConsumedQty, @OrigForecastQty_c, @SumOrderQty, @NewForecastQty, @NewInactive, @LastUpdatedDate);
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to a) clean up the indentation so your code is easier to read, and b) provide an explanation of what you’re doing here and why you believe it’s the best approach to solving the original problem? That will make this answer more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is `@ForeDate` is a `DATE`, not a `VARCHAR`. Even if you fix the syntax error by using `''` instead of `""`, dates can't contain empty strings as values, so your `NULLIF(@ForeDate, '')`, while it can potentially still work, is not proper date syntax, and can lead to unexpected future behavior.

## Solution 1

Check the user's input in advance in your application, and, if it's an empty string, store `NULL` instead.

## Solution 2

If you'd rather stick to a pure SQL solution, check for the minimum date instead of an empty string.

```
insert into dbo.ExampleDb (..., ForeDate, ...)
values (..., ForeDate = NULLIF(@ForeDate, '1900-01-01'), ...);
```